# Reconcile users with logins using 'sp_change_users_login'

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, security

`Sql Server 2008 (and 2005)`:

I have a Sql Server instance, let's say, **InstA**, in a Domain (called **AD**). In that I have a domain Windows Authentication Login, called **AD\Log1** that has an associated user, **User1** in a database called **DB1**.

So, now I backup this database and restore on a new instance (**Inst2**) that is **not** part of any domain. It has an existing login (**LocalMachine\Log2**) that I need to have mapped to the existing **User1** in the newly restored database **DB1**.

With sp_change_users_login, I get the following error:

`EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Update_One', 'User1', 'LocalMachine\Log2'`

`Msg 15291, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_change_users_login, Line 114
Terminating this procedure. The User name 'User1' is absent or invalid.`

If I use `ALTER USER User1 WITH LOGIN = 'LocalMachine\Log2'`, it renames the user **User1** to **LocalMachine\Log2** and maps it to **LocalMachine\Log2** login. It works, but I do not want it to rename.

I would prefer to map this existing database user **User1** in the database **DB1** to an existing login in the new instance **inst2** without changing the user name or creating a new login (`AutoFix`). Just update the SID and map it (without other changes).

**Is it possible?**

What I gathered so far is, for my situation, `sp_change_users_login` does not work because **LocalMachine\Log1** is a Windows Account (not a Sql Login). but if both were Sql Logins, `sp_change_users_login` with work perfectly.

Thanks,

Comment: How do you expect it to authenticate if its login is associated with a Windows principal that can't be verified since `Inst2` is not on the domain??

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your comment. But `Inst2` has its own login: `Log2`. I want `Log2`'s SID to be mapped to the DB user `User1`. Does it help?

Comment: Did you try also specifying `WITH NAME = User2`?

Comment: From what I read from [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx): `WITH NAME = User2` renames `user1` to `user2`.

Comment: @JonSeigel I do not want to rename after mapping `User1` to `Log2`. It's not about avoiding the extra step, I am trying to understand (1) why it does not work and (2) why does it rename?

Comment: Just a second ago, I edited my Original Post with more info about Login: **Log2** (supposed to be `LocalMachine\Log2`  --  **Local machine Windows Account**)

Comment: Sorry, typo. I meant `User1` (i.e., the existing user name). I have no idea why it renames automatically.

Comment: The BOL article linked to by @UB01 explains the behavior:  

`"The name of the user will be automatically renamed to the login name if the following conditions are true.

The user is a Windows user.

The name is a Windows name (contains a backslash).

No new name was specified.

The current name differs from the login name."`

I would think the **name** of the database user wouldn't really be material, since it should retain the same database_principal_id and permissions.

Comment: @kozloski Thank you, that was a good observation. The whole time, it was right in front of my face, but I did not pay attention. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you run sp_change_users_login, it automatically [renames users as explained in Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx):

> The name of the user will be automatically renamed to the login name
>   if the following conditions are true. The user is a Windows user. The
>   name is a Windows name (contains a backslash). No new name was
>   specified. The current name differs from the login name.

To keep life easy, I'd keep the same usernames on both servers and then you should be fine with sp_change_users_login.